# Serialization errors due to jackson-databind version mismatch?

Tags: maven, serialization, dropwizard, jackson-modules

I am running into the following error

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: WRITE_DURATIONS_AS_TIMESTAMPS
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.ser.DurationSerializer.<init>(DurationSerializer.java:28)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.ser.DurationSerializer.<init>(DurationSerializer.java:25)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.JodaModule.<init>(JodaModule.java:45)
```

I checked to see what versions of jackson-datatype-joda are available. It appears that maven has excluded all version mismatches.

Any other reason this might cause serialization errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it resolved by using following dependency as this dependency has overridden any other version used:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-joda</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that among the maven dependencies (mind that it could be a transitive one) you have incompatible versions of **jackson-datatype-joda** and **jackson-databind**. Incompatible in the sense that **jackson-databind**'s **SerializationFeature** class is missing the **WRITE_DURATIONS_AS_TIMESTAMPS** field. To see what dependencies maven brings you can run the following command in the terminal (or you can use an IDE's maven plug to search and analyse the maven dependency tree):

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep databind
```

the outcome will most probably be something like:

```
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.1:compile
```

The version of course can vary but the important thing is that the **WRITE_DURATIONS_AS_TIMESTAMPS** field is only available since version **2.5**

You can exclude a transitive dependency like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>group.id</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact-id</artifactId>
  <version>${artifact.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

If it's not a transitive dependency you need to update version of **jackson-databind**.

Answer (score 0):

I had same error. I had included all jackson*2.7.0 libraries under WEB-INF/lib/ and i was still getting that error. I am using wildfly 8.2 and it had jackson 2.4.1 libraries under modules and somehow it was loading 2.4.1 jars from that location. So I had to manually upgrade them to 2.7.0 which fixed the issue. I was under impression that if I did not mention it to load jackson jars in deployment configuration file, it would not load wildfly jars. I guess I was wrong.